# Catch url with no route

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2

To catch an *url* which doesn't have a route one can do something like this

```
services.AddMvc()
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2).AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Error/Nopage", "{*url}");
    });
```

But then I noticed that the `OnGet()` method in `Nopage.cshtml.cs` gets called for all routes, even the one's that has a route.

Is this the standard behavior, and how one is suppose to catch non-routed *url's*? ...or is there some other way to catch *url* with no routes.

Also, from a workload/performance perspective, it feels kind of wrong to initiate and load a page model that will not be used.

---

As a note, prior to using `AddPageRoute` I did like this in `Startup.cs`, which worked just fine, though the above felt more as *how one is suppose to do it*.

```
app.UseMvc();

// Page missing in MVC...
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    //simplified code snippet
    s = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, "pagemissing.html"));
    await context.Response.WriteAsync(s);
});
```

Comment: Your original approach seems fine. I don't see a reason to handle it in the MVC middleware unless you need MVC features for the response.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Thanks for your comment.Two things: 1) Given that I have logging logic etc. in MVC I would like to handle it there. 2) I added a break point in the initial approach and it actual hit that as well, but I am sure I saw somewhere that code after `app.UseMvc();` won't run if it is handled in MVC, but here it appear that isn't true.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce this with a similar setup and it works as I'd expect. I get my custom page for non-matching routes but get the correct response for pages that do exist.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Thanks. I'm gonna create a new default project and see if that one will work as you say it should.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using `StatusCodePages` Middleware? https://www.learnrazorpages.com/configuration/custom-errors

Comment: @MikeBrind Yes...being completely unaware of its existence :). To my defence (I hope), I just moved from "VB.Net/WebForms/WebHandlers/CodeBehind" to "C#/MVC/RazorPages", and as there is quite a big difference in their logic + have to learn C# from scratch on top of it, it's gonna take some time before I will start searching for the solution in the right location. Thank you very much, will look into that as well.

Comment: @MikeBrind If you post that as an answer I will accept, as after reading a lot of articles, I find that being the best solution to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to intercept 404s and return a custom error page. ASP.NET Core includes middeleware that does this: StatusCodePagesMiddleware. You put the following in your `Configure` method:

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/{0}");
```

where `{0}` is a placeholder for the status code. Create a page called *404.cshtml* and it will be executed whenever someone browses to a non-existent URL. You can also create a page named *500.cshtml* and it will be executed if there is a server error.

See more about this here: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/configuration/custom-errors